# find the next element with particular class in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to find the next tr element which has particular class from the current tr. If the immediate next tr does not have that class(opened) I want to get the next tr with opened class. How to do this in angular js

template

```
<tr ng-repeat-start = "item in xx"  ng-class="{'opened': item.ddd == 0 || item.ddd == undefined,'closed': item.ddd == 1}">
```

Some code for td
ggff

js

```
app.directive("moveNext", function() {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function($scope, element) {

        element.on('td, keyup' ,function(e) {
             var nextele =  element.parents('tr').next('.opened');

        });
    }
}
});
```

Comment: try with (jqlite https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) children(). and with result return to DOM of javascript to get class and comparte it

Comment: I want to the  next tr which has the class opened

Comment: then use .next() ,even children

Comment: I am using next only(please refer my code). The problem is all my tr doesn't have opened class only a few. I want to get the next opened class tr.  If the immediate  next tr doesn't have 'opened' class, I want the next tr which has opened class

Comment: please, read the doc of jqlite, that you are using, and is native from angular. next() Does not support selectors, so you cant use next('tr'), or any. So i give you the idea of using children to get all, and then decide.

Comment: yes you are correct, that's the reason I am searching next element by class. If go with children option how can I check the next tr of current tr, I can get only all tr , then I search for class it result in the top most element, which may cause the current element

Answer (score 0):

At last i've got a little time to make you a [fddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QrCXh/1717/), expect i understand you at all:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h2>DEMO</h2>
    <table>
        <tr ng-click="getAll($event.currentTarget)" ng-repeat = "item in xx"  ng-class="{'opened': item.ddd == 0 || item.ddd == undefined,'closed': item.ddd == 1}">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</div>
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])

    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.getAll=function(e){
            var elms = angular.element(e).parent().find('tr');
          var elm = null;
          for(var i =0; i<elms.length; i++){
            console.log(/opened/.test(angular.element(elms[i]).attr('class')));
            if(/opened/.test(angular.element(elms[i]).attr('class'))){
                elm = angular.element(elms[i]);
              break;
            }   
          }
            console.log('all', angular.element(e).parent().find('tr'), 'only the nex at clicked', elm);
        };
        $scope.xx =[{
            name: 'uno',
            ddd:1
        },{
            name:'open-1',
            ddd:0
        },{
            name:'tres',
            ddd:1
        },{
        name: 'open-2',
        ddd:0
        }];
    }]);
```